# use Firestore for storing profile data with "react-redux-firebase"?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-redux, react-redux-firebase

I want to use firestore to store the profile data using "react-redux-firebase". My expected output of firebase.profile looks like this in the console
[Expected output of the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hlqWP.png)
but my output is

```
profile: {isEmpty: true, isLoaded: false}
```

this is my index.js file

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import * as serviceWorker from "./serviceWorker";
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from "redux";
import rootReducer from "./store/reducres/rooReducers";

import { Provider, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import {
  reduxFirestore,
  getFirestore,
  createFirestoreInstance
} from "redux-firestore";
import { ReactReduxFirebaseProvider, getFirebase, isLoaded} from "react-redux-firebase";
import fbConfig from "./config/fbConfig";
import firebase from "firebase/app";


const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  compose(
    applyMiddleware(thunk.withExtraArgument({ getFirestore, getFirebase })),
    reduxFirestore(firebase, fbConfig)
  )
);

const profileSpecificProps = {
  userProfile: 'users',
  useFirestoreForProfile: true,
  enableRedirectHandling: false,
  resetBeforeLogin: false
}


const rrfProps = {
  firebase,
  config: profileSpecificProps,
  dispatch: store.dispatch,
  createFirestoreInstance
};

function AuthIsLoaded({ children }) {
  const auth = useSelector(state => state.firebase.auth)
  if (!isLoaded(auth)) return <div className="center"> <p>Loading Mario Plan...</p></div>;
      return children
}


ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <ReactReduxFirebaseProvider {...rrfProps}>
      <AuthIsLoaded>
      <App />
      </AuthIsLoaded>
      
    </ReactReduxFirebaseProvider>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

the full preview of the project link
[full project link](https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-http-zo0gb?file=/src/store/reducres/rooReducers.js)
any ideas what's going wrong?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that RRF will not create the new profile record for you.  It will query it and it will update it, but it won't create it.  If a userProfile record entry doesn't exist, you won't see any additional info in firebase.profile.

You need to create the record for users.  RRF can *update* an existing profile record; see http://react-redux-firebase.com/docs/recipes/profile.html#update-profile.

Comment: Note: the ID of the document in the userProfile collection must match the UID of the user you are authenticating as.  For example if in Firebase Console >> Authentication your user has UID is X0001234, and if you set `userProfile: "my_users"`, then RRF will retrieve document `my_users/X0001234` to update the Redux node: firebase.profile

Comment: @mobiGeek I don't want to create the new file record. Actually I just wanted to replicate this code from youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ykSYDRHheNI&list=PL4cUxeGkcC9iWstfXntcj8f-dFZ4UtlN3&index=29
but the method ninja uses I quite outdated... and reading the comments doesn't helped either. I just want to replicate that code

Comment: You do want to create a new record.  In fact, your code is already attempting to do it in your authActions >> signup() right after `.createUserWithEmailAndPassword()` in the `then()` clause.  But for some reason, you are getting errors when the call to createUserWithEmailAndPassword() is happening.  Try signing up a new user and check out the console for error messages.

Comment: Yeah, I looked in it and fortunately, I found the error. Thanks for the help @mobiGeek

Answer (score 2):

I think we are following the same tutorial.

The only thing that I think you missed is the `fbConfig` in the `rrrfProps`.

This worked fine for me :

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import rootReducers from './store/reducers/rootReducer';
import { Provider, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import { getFirebase, reactReduxFirebase, ReactReduxFirebaseProvider, isLoaded } from 'react-redux-firebase';
import { getFirestore, reduxFirestore, createFirestoreInstance } from 'redux-firestore';
import fbConfig from './config/fbConfig';
import firebase from 'firebase/app'

const store = createStore(rootReducers, 
  compose(
  applyMiddleware(thunk.withExtraArgument({getFirebase, getFirestore})),
    reduxFirestore(firebase, fbConfig)
  )
)
const rrfConfig = {
  userProfile: 'users',
  useFirestoreForProfile: true
}
const rrfProps = {
  firebase,
  config: rrfConfig, fbConfig,
  dispatch: store.dispatch,
  createFirestoreInstance,
}

const AuthIsLoaded = ({children}) => {
  const auth = useSelector(state => state.firebase.auth)
  if(!isLoaded(auth)) return <div className="center">Loading...</div>
  return children
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store = {store}>
      <ReactReduxFirebaseProvider {...rrfProps}>
        <AuthIsLoaded>
          <App />
        </AuthIsLoaded>
      </ReactReduxFirebaseProvider>
      </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

Answer (score 1):

I also did this tutorial and this is the working index I came out with. There are areas where the tutorial is out-of-date, but I followed the YT comments and got the project working.
Of note, mine also includes Redux DevTool extension, which is a nice problem solving tool!

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
import * as serviceWorker from "./serviceWorker";
import { createStore, compose, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import rootReducer from "./store/reducers/index";

import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import ReduxThunk from "redux-thunk";
import {
  reduxFirestore,
  getFirestore,
  createFirestoreInstance,
} from "redux-firestore";
import { ReactReduxFirebaseProvider, getFirebase } from "react-redux-firebase";
import firebaseConfig from "./config/firebase";
import firebase from "firebase/app";

const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  compose(
    applyMiddleware(
      ReduxThunk.withExtraArgument({ getFirestore, getFirebase })
    ),
    reduxFirestore(firebase, firebaseConfig),
    window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
  )
);

const profileSpecificProps = {
  userProfile: "users",
  useFirestoreForProfile: true,
  enableRedirectHandling: false,
  resetBeforeLogin: false,
};

const rrfProps = {
  firebase,
  config: profileSpecificProps,
  dispatch: store.dispatch,
  createFirestoreInstance,
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <ReactReduxFirebaseProvider {...rrfProps}>
      <App />
    </ReactReduxFirebaseProvider>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your profile specific props config should look like this:

```
const profileSpecificProps = {
  userProfile: 'users',
  useFirestoreForProfile: true,
  updateProfileOnLogin: false,
};
```